# Applet does not receive mouse movement events in Opera

Tags: java, applet, opera

I wrote an applet, which needs to receive mouse events from the user. The problem is - it works for all other browsers, but in **Opera** it receives only `mouse wheel events` and `mouse pressed/clicked events`.

And so I am not able to get the location of the mouse on the component.
It's clearly an **Opera** bug because sometimes it magically starts working (without any changes to my app), then after a reload it stops working.

So the question is - have you encountered this problem, and is there a way to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opera here. Is this limited to a particular operating system? Do you have some sample code or demo? You're missing mousemove, x, y etc.? We are currently improving this area so would be good to know if we already fixed this or not.

Comment: In fact, it was a problem of 10.10 Opera. I upgraded yesterday, and 10.63 everything works flawlessly.